# Methods for finding a relatively prime integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, primorial

Here's the problem:

Given a prime $p$ and an integer $x$, find an integer $c$ such that $gcd(x+c,p\#)=1$ where $p\#$ is the primorial for $p$.

It is straight forward to solve this problem using brute force or the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Is there any other methods that can be used to find $c$?  Ideally, it would be interesting to find the minimal $c$ where $gcd(x+c,p\#)=1$.

Thanks,

-Larry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$c=p\#-x+1$ clearly is a solution.
Cheap,but a solution.
The minimal $c$ if i am not mistaken is conjectured to be at the worst case $O(p^2)$ but i think this is still open.
***EDIT***:
It is known from the prime number theorem that $ln(p\#)\sim p$
So if you look at http://oeis.org/wiki/Jacobsthal_function you can see that indeed $c\sim O(p^2)$ is valid if we consider the worst case for the number $x$.
Of course though, $x$ could be an appropriate number (for example $x=p\#-1$) wich allows us to consider even the case $c=0$

Comment: Do you have any reference on where the conjecture on the minimal c comes from?  That sounds very interesting.

Comment: @Larry Freeman i made an edit i hope that the answer seems much better.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  I think that the answer that I was looking for is in the article listed at your link: The best known upper bound:
$ j(n) << log^{2}n$
is due to Iwaniec [H. Iwaniec, On the problem of Jacobsthal, Demonstratio Math. 11, 225{231, (1978).].  Thanks!